# Authentication using PHP to consume wsdl

Tags: php, authentication, soap, wsdl

I'm having trouble connecting to a wsdl service through PHP.  The trouble seems to come in authentication.  Here is my code so far:

```
$soapURL = "http://myurl?wsdl";
    $soapLogin = Array(
        'User ID'=>'myusername', 
        'Password'=>"mypassword"
        );
$soapClient = new SoapClient($soapURL, $soapLogin);
$soapResult = $soapClient->mySoapFunction();
```

I have the username and password as defined by the client, and I can see the XML file that the wsdl generates but no I cannot discern if I am referencing the username and passwords correctly.  When trying to connect I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InvalidSecurity] An error occurred when verifying security for the message. in E:\xampp\htdocs\TRMSosf\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\TRMSosf\index.php(15): SoapClient->__call('GetWeekEvents', Array) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\TRMSosf\index.php(15): SoapClient->GetWeekEvents('10', '20130527') #2 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\TRMSosf\index.php on line 15
```

I'm new to using SOAP and fairly new to PHP, any help is appreciated.

Comment: change key User ID to login

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another article here:  [Can I get Code Samples working with php and wsse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927822/can-i-get-code-samples-working-with-php-and-wsse)

it involved a class that handled the WSSE authentication

```
class WSSESoapClient extends SoapClient {                                                                                           
protected $wsseUser;
protected $wssePassword;

public function setWSSECredentials($user, $password) {
$this->wsseUser = $user;
$this->wssePassword = $password;
}

public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
if (!$this->wsseUser or !$this->wssePassword) {

    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0);
}

// get SOAP message into DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($request);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace('SOAP-ENV', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

// search for SOAP header, create one if not found
$header = $xp->query('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Header')->item(0);
if (!$header) {
    $header = $dom->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'SOAP-ENV:Header');
    $envelope = $xp->query('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope')->item(0);
    $envelope->insertBefore($header, $xp->query('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body')->item(0));
}

// add WSSE header
$usernameToken = $dom->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext', 'wsse:UsernameToken');
$username = $dom->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext', 'wsse:Username', $this->wsseUser);
$password = $dom->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext', 'wsse:Password', $this->wssePassword);
$usernameToken->appendChild($username);
$usernameToken->appendChild($password);
$header->appendChild($usernameToken);

// perform SOAP call
$request = $dom->saveXML();

return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0);
```

}